# onChange isn't showing data, but it is calling it correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
const handleInputDropdownChange = (e) => {
    //console.log(e.target.name + e.target.value);
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
};


<Field className="dropwdown" name="applicaiton_type" as="select" id="application_type" onChange={handleInputDropdownChange}>
    <option value="">Select Application Type</option>
    <optgroup label="app group 1">
      <option value="1">App 1</option>
      <option value="2">App2 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="app group 2">
      <option value="3">App 3</option>
      <option value="4">App 4</option>
    </optgroup>

</Field>
```

^^ Not Working ^^

When I attempt to select on the drop down, it doesn't display it how a onSelect would. But it stores it in the database correct even though it doesn't display it. How would I get both functionalities of onSelect and onChange?

VV Working VV

```
<Field className="dropwdown" name="vac_ban" as="select" id="vac_ban" onChange={handleInputDropdownChange}>
        <option value="">Do you have a vac ban?</option>
          <option value="true">Yes</option>
          <option value="false">No</option>
</Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the state by calling the `setState` method. This will start the reconciliation cycle of react and will update the UI as expected by you.

```
const handleInputDropdownChange = (e) => {
    setState((state)=>{
     state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    })
};


<Field className="dropwdown" name="applicaiton_type" as="select" id="application_type" onChange={handleInputDropdownChange}>
    <option value="">Select Application Type</option>
    <optgroup label="app group 1">
      <option value="1">App 1</option>
      <option value="2">App2 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="app group 2">
      <option value="3">App 3</option>
      <option value="4">App 4</option>
    </optgroup>

</Field>
```

Comment: I get an error,  Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: Could you please share the complete component code?